# Not able to scan hbm files and build mappings?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
try {
        // Add mapping locations
        PropertyValue mappingLocationsProp = properties.getPropertyValue("mappingLocations");
        if (mappingLocationsProp != null) {
            List<TypedStringValue> mappingLocations = (List<TypedStringValue>) mappingLocationsProp.getValue();
            if (mappingLocations != null) {
                ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
                for (TypedStringValue mappingLocation : mappingLocations) {
                    LOG.info("Found mappingLocation " + mappingLocation.getValue());
                    Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(mappingLocation.getValue());
                    for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
                        LOG.info("Adding resource  " + resources[i].getURL());
                        try {
                            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                            // Disable DTD resolution
                            documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {

                                @Override
                                public InputSource resolveEntity(String arg0, String arg1) throws SAXException, IOException {
                                    return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
                                }
                            });
                            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(resources[i].getInputStream());
                            config.addDocument(document);
                        } catch (SAXException e) {
                            throw new DatabaseException("Error reading document " + resources[i].getURL(), e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof DatabaseException) {
            throw (DatabaseException) e;
        } else {
            throw new DatabaseException(e);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to build configuration and build mapping files from it like this. `config.buildMappings();`
In **hibernateTestContext.xml** I have defined the mapping location as :

```
<property name="mappingLocations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath*:../WEB-INF/mapping/*/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

I have my hbms in `E:\*\web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mapping`
But still I am not able to scan the `hbms`. I also have tried using `file:../web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mapping/*/*.hbm.xml`
But I got this exception:

`org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from unknown`

full error: `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [testHole] not found on org.test.*.*.synchronization.hole.Hole`

Reading and building hibernate config file:

```
` Configuration config = new Configuration();

    // Disable xml validation
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);

    // Read configuration
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = new SimpleBeanDefinitionRegistry();
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(registry);
    reader.setNamespaceAware(true);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource(connection.getPath()));`
```

Comment: Can you try with two stars instead of one? like mapping/**/**.hbm.xml

Comment: @aksappy Nope, even two stars does not work. What is that for, by the way?

Comment: two stars are regex expressions for matching any number of directory levels, one star basically checks only one directory level.

Comment: How is your hibernate config loaded?

Comment: I am building the configuration file by reading a property parameter like this: **referenceUrl**: hibernate:spring:hibernateTestContext.xml?bean=sessionFactory.

I have added my code above too.

Comment: Is there no "cause" in your stack trace? Can you post it entirely?

Comment: I have pasted the error above.